# How to have one class have three different colors?

Tags: html, css

I am working with a template. The client is wanting the three buttons different colors. All three are controlled by the same class. I can change the background color to be different if I inspect the page and I can insert it in the element style. How can I make this change permanent in the CSS?

This is the current buttons:
[image: This is the current buttons:]

This is how the client would like the buttons:
[image: This is how the client would like the buttons:]

The CSS controlling this is:

```
    .full-width .generic .third p a {
     background-color: #543D91;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
     color: #fff;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     padding: 10px 0;
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 99em; 
     }
```

How can I change this so that each button is a different color? Is this even possible? It has to be done in CSS. I can not use JavaScript/jQuery or anything like it. It has to work in a JSFiddle in only the CSS and HTML. Note that the HTML is created only the label for each button. I cannot make the hyperlink have a style.

If this is not possible can you please give me the codes that I can have 3 images centered with buttons in a container that is 900px with padding between? I appreciate everyones help!

Comment: I wonder, can you edit the current style sheet? Or at least add your own?

Comment: @T. Heuerman, Please post also your html code so we can give a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 classes and create a CSS like:

```css
.cls {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: #F00;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.c3 {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<button class="cls c1">Button1</button>
<button class="cls c2">Button2</button>
<button class="cls c3">Button3</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to solve your question using jQuery, try and have a look, it's simple and works like magic:

This is the dummy HTML:

```
<div id="searchable">
   <a>
   Something
   </a>
   <button>
   Something
   </button>
   <a>
   Something2
   </a>
   <button>
   Something2
   </button>
   <a>
   Something3
   </a>
   <button>
   Something3
   </button>
</div>
```

This is the required jQuery for this:

```
var buttons = $("#searchable").find("button");
var color = ["red", "blue", "green"];
buttons.each(function(i){
    $(this).css('color', color[i]);
});
```

Here is a link to my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x5ve63w5/1/